# How to check mandatory fields are filled in a state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    country: { country: "India" },
    address: { street1: "street1", street2: "street2",city:'City1',state:'Kerala',zip:'695505' },
    banking: { bankRoutingNumber:'3453453',bankAccountNumber:'4242424242424242',confirmBankAccountNumber:'4242424242424242'},
    personalInformation:{providerNpi:'',prefix:'',firstName:'',lastName:'',suffix:'',dob:'',fullSsn:'',sex:''},
    practiceInformation:{practiceName:'',practiceNpi:'',practiceTaxIdNumber:'',practiceWebAddress:''}
  });
```

This is my state here `street2` ,`suffix`,`practiceTaxIdNumber` are optional fields

```
const onValuePicked = useCallback(
(value, fieldId,sectionId) => {

     const updatedObject={
        ...fields,
        [sectionId]: { ...fields[sectionId], [fieldId]: value }}
  setFields(updatedObject);
},
[fields]
);
```

This is how I update the value.
What is the best-optimized way to check all mandatory fields are entered while each time the state changes?

Comment: can you please describe how you are showing error message? like error message will be combination of all fields or it will be individual?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Submit button will be active only if all the mandatory fields exist

Comment: Can u also show us the code for Submit, like how is it checking for mandate fields